# findLastIndex() not working in FireFox, Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array of duplicate `objects`.

I have to find allways last duplicate, and remove it from `array`.

In Chrome i use `findLastIndex`, to get the index, and remove it. Sadly FireFox does not support that function.

Any other idea how to get last index of `duplicate` object in `array`, in simple way?

(to find my `object` I use property `name: string`, I dont have Id, thats why I need the Index.

I have already tried to use `myArr.lastIndexOf(myArr.find((item) => item.name == itemName));` but it doesnt work.

Here is example of array:

```js
[{
    imgSource: "/sushi/test2.png"
    ingredients: "Nori, Cucumber, Rice, Cream cheese, Sesame, Unagi sauce"
    name: "sushi1"
    price: 133
    weight: 120
  },
  {
    imgSource: "/sushi/test2.png"
    ingredients: "Nori, Cucumber, Rice, Cream cheese, Sesame, Unagi sauce"
    name: "sushi1"
    price: 133
    weight: 120
  },
  {
    imgSource: "/sushi/test3.png"
    ingredients: "Rice, Cream cheese, Sesame"
    name: "sushi3"
    price: 150
    weight: 100
  }
]
```

Comment: `findLastIndex` is not a standard JavaScript function.

Comment: It should be simple to write your own `for` loop that does the same thing.

Comment: You can reverse the array, call `findIndex`, then subtract that from the array length.

Comment: @Barmar allright, didnt know that, thank you.

Comment: @Barmar ok im gonna add what i have tried to do :)

Comment: [The proposal](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-array-find-from-last) provides a link to several [polyfils](https://www.npmjs.com/package/array.prototype.findlastindex).

Comment: Also those are not really "duplicate" objects; they *look* the same, but every object is distinct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have finally found solution for my answer, thanks to Mohamad ali ghorbani, I managed to find right way to do it.

Here is how i got my last Index:

```
  const nameArray = myCart.map((item) => item.name);

  const indexOfItem = nameArray.lastIndexOf(itemName);

  myCart.splice(indexOfItem, 1);
```

Answer (score 1):

`findLastIndex` is not a js function, but I think what you are trying to do is something like this:

```js
let arr = [
    {
        imgSource: "/sushi/test2.png",
        ingredients: "Nori, Cucumber, Rice, Cream cheese, Sesame, Unagi sauce",
        name: "sushi1",
        price: 133,
        weight: 120,
    },
    {
        imgSource: "/sushi/test2.png",
        ingredients: "Nori, Cucumber, Rice, Cream cheese, Sesame, Unagi sauce",
        name: "sushi1",
        price: 133,
        weight: 120,
    },
    {
        imgSource: "/sushi/test3.png",
        ingredients: "Rice, Cream cheese, Sesame",
        name: "sushi3",
        price: 150,
        weight: 100,
    },
];



let lastIndex = arr.lastIndexOf(arr.reverse().find(ele=>ele.name=="sushi1"))
console.log(lastIndex)
```

note that I used the `reverse()` function for `find()` because u need the last one.

extra note: these duplicate objects are not the same in `==` or `===` point of view, as the quality check operators for objects, check the references and not the actual value

Comment: I tried your solution myself, but it returns only first index of duplicate anyway.

Comment: I finally found solution, thanks to your answer, I found right way to do it. Thank you Sir

Comment: findLastIndex is not a JS function?  what is this then https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findLastIndex

Comment: @G-T , at the time the question was asked (Feb 2022) It was not a js function (believe me, it was not in the MDN docs) . if you look the link you shared, with more accuracy, you will see it is added from node version 18.x, that the LTS release date was Oct 2022). and check here [github commit history for the url you shared](https://github.com/mdn/content/commits/main/files/en-us/web/javascript/reference/global_objects/array/findlastindex)

Comment: @mohammad ali , yes you are right, on replit or on leetcode I am still getting this error that - 'findLastIndex  is not a function' while on codesabdbox it works fine, maybe because replit and leetcode are running on older Node version servers?

Answer (score 0):

There is no findLastIndex in JS

You can make a set

```js
let  arr = [{
    imgSource: "/sushi/test2.png",
    ingredients: "Nori, Cucumber, Rice, Cream cheese, Sesame, Unagi sauce",
    name: "sushi1",
    price: 133,
    weight: 120
  },
  {
    imgSource: "/sushi/test2.png",
    ingredients: "Nori, Cucumber, Rice, Cream cheese, Sesame, Unagi sauce",
    name: "sushi1",
    price: 133,
    weight: 120
  },
  {
    imgSource: "/sushi/test3.png",
    ingredients: "Rice, Cream cheese, Sesame",
    name: "sushi3",
    price: 150,
    weight: 100
  }
]

const mySet = new Set()
arr.forEach(item => mySet.add(JSON.stringify(item)))
const newArr = Array.from(mySet).map(entry => JSON.parse(entry))

console.log(newArr)
```

Comment: It actually removes all other duplicates, and leave me only with single object, of each duplicated object.

Comment: And what is the aim? To only remove ONE duplicate?

Comment: yes, aim was to remova last duplicate of array, but i have solved the problem allready and posted my answer